# ZK Listheader set sort programmatically

Tags: java, sorting, listbox, zk

I have a listheader like this

```
<listheader id='lh3' label="Quantity" sort="auto(lower(value))"/>
```

I need to remove the sort sometime I have use this method.

```
final Listheader header = .....
header.setSort(null);
```

But it stills have the sort attribute I cannot get the sort because the header doesn't have a `getSort()` method this is a kind of weird!

I am doing it all wrong? What can I do to remove the sort attribute programmatically.

Comment: Please give us a working example on http://zkfiddle.org/ for us to see what is happening. Your explanation is not very clear. For starters: keep in mind that `setSort()` only tells the list **how** to sort, but to **force it to sort**, you should try [`sort(boolean, boolean)`](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/8.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Listheader.html#sort(boolean,%20boolean)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort` attribute can be a field, an expression, or "none".

So just try this :

```
final Listheader header = .....
header.setSort("none");
```